# Despite heavily dependent on JVM, how Java is platform independent?

Tags: java, c++, jvm

If any `Java` program require a `JVM` running in order to execute, why does `Java` is said to be **Platform Independent**?

When I used `C++` programs, I needed `Turbo C` complier; and when I have a `Java` program, I need to have `JVM`. ***Still C++ isn't platform independent, but Java is!***

*Although I have been a Java developer for almost 2 years now, but always had this doubt in mind.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need a compiler (and certainly not an antique like Turbo C) to run a C++ program, just to build it. But once built, it will only run on some platforms (whether or not they have a compiler, or any other software, installed) while a Java program will run on any platform that has a JVM. That's what "independence" means in this context.

Comment: i.e. it is "platform independent" for platforms with a JVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First thing to remember** is that Java has been termed as a Platform Independent Language as it primarily works on the core principles of '***compile once, run everywhere**'.

*Now as you remember* what Platform Independence means, we will further break this this phrase into **Platform** & **Independence**. **Platform** means the components of the computer hardware, basically architecture of the microprocessor and OS. **Independence** simply means freedom.

When Java is said to be **Platform Independent**, it means Java program can **run on any operating system** and hardware without altering any line in the code.

> **Now the question is how it is platform independent?**

Basically, a compiled code is a set of instructions for CPU to execute the program. When Java program is compiled, the resultant byte code is the set of instructions for a **Virtual CPU**. This virtual CPU takes care of interpreting this byte code differently for different platforms but execute it in exactly same fashion everywhere.

**This virtual CPU, in Java, is called JVM, aka Java Virtual Machine.**

The early authors of Java understood this and kept all the platform dependency of Java into a virtual machine, and keeping the Java programming language independent of platforms.

Comment: So **any operating system** and hardware runs the JVM? Interesting...

Comment: If its created then yes, JVM can run on anything if made for it..

Comment: @JIV If what is created? If made for what?

Comment: if aliens make it to earth, we just need someone to make JVM app for their HW. So answer is yes, JVM can (if created) run on everything :) JVM is just specification.

Comment: And JVM cannot be made for every hardware.